# Subquery as field in querydsl

Tags: inheritance, subquery, querydsl

I just ran into some problems.

I want to write subquery according to the SQL using querydsl.

SQL(ps: v_task_recipient is a view.)

`select v.title, v.create_date_time from v_task_recipient v
where 
(select r.branch_id from tbl_recipient r where v.recipient_id = r.id) 
in 
(2704230,2703041,2702932);`

in java part, I write like this:

```
List<Branch> branches = user.getBranchesForPermissionOperation(Operations.claim_update);

    ListSubQuery<Branch> subquery =  new JPASubQuery().from(branchRecipient).where(taskRecipentView.recipient_id.eq(branchRecipient.id)).list(branchRecipient.branch);
    for(Branch branch: branches)
    {
        ex = ex == null ? subquery.contains(branch) : ex.or(subquery.contains(branch)); 
    }
```

is there any better solution to avoid the ugly for loop? can I use some expression just like 'in'?

and the most difficult part is branchRecipient is inherited from the parent recipient.

```
private static QRecipient recipient = QRecipient.recipient;
private static QBranchRecipient branchRecipient = recipient.as(QBranchRecipient.class);
private static QUserRecipient userRecipient = recipient.as(QUserRecipient.class);
```

it always cause the exception

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Undeclared path 'recipient'. Add this path as a source to the query to be able to reference it.